# MySQL Partition by Range on YEAR(date) wrong results

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `adverts_stats_clicks` (
 `advert_stats_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `advertisment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `catdom_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `added_on` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `ipfrom` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `click_on` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `click_from` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `click_from_path` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`advert_stats_id`,`added_on`),
 KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`),
 KEY `click_on` (`click_on`),
 KEY `advertisment_id` (`advertisment_id`),
 KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
 KEY `added_on` (`added_on`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=48176808 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(added_on))
(PARTITION ac0 VALUES LESS THAN (2005) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac1 VALUES LESS THAN (2006) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac2 VALUES LESS THAN (2007) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac3 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac4 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac5 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac6 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac7 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac8 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac9 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION ac99 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

Then if I run the following query:

```
SELECT advert_stats_id 
  FROM adverts_stats_clicks 
 WHERE domain_id = 618 
   AND click_on = 'www' 
   AND click_from IN('sel','top','s','e','adv') 
   AND advertisment_id = 6122
   AND added_on BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2014-12-31';
```

I get for example 152 results. But if I change the date range as fllows:

```
SELECT advert_stats_id 
  FROM adverts_stats_clicks 
 WHERE domain_id = 618 
   AND click_on = 'www' 
   AND click_from IN('sel','top','s','e','adv') 
   AND advertisment_id = 6122
   AND added_on BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2014-12-31';
```

I get 643 results. Which is nonsense as the previous date range is bigger than the second.
If I run explain partitions I get the following:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  adverts_stats_clicks    ac7,ac8,ac9 index_merge     domain_id,click_on,advertisment_id,added_on     advertisment_id,domain_id   4,4     NULL    114     Using intersect(advertisment_id,domain_id); Using where
```

So in the first query the correct partitions (ac7,ac8,ac9) were selected. This proves that pruning is working. For the second query also the correct partitions were selected (ac8, ac9)  however the results retrieved by both cannot be trusted.

What is happening ??? Why is like this?

Some extra info from sever variables in case it might me important to figure out.

```
Variable_name   Value   
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Please help and ask additional questions if you need more info in order to help.

Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, it appears you're missing a partition for 2008.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using  BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2014-12-31';
your checking a value in between two strings...
'2013-10-01' will take as a string...

so if we want to check between the dates..string should be converted to dates..
use str_to_date() function

Comment: Completely wrong. `'2013-10-01'` is a valid date token. It's represented as a string literal and will be parsed correctly by MySQL

Comment: str_to_date should be used to convert string into date when ever we want to compare dates other was the result will be wrong..

Comment: What you are saying is wrong. In MySQL, string literals are ok to use them as dates.